# Where / How can I see the .NET WPF implementation of databinding?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

Since .NET has source code exposed http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/07/12/step-into-net-framework-4-0-source-code.aspx

Where and how could I find .NET WPF implementation of databinding ? I'd like to see how it's implemented just by curiosity.

Comment: I know that's the url I'm pointing to :) What I need is precisely what classes to look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best start might be by reading the code of [the Binding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx)

That is where most of the magic is.

On a side note: you don't need to download the source code for that. You could use Reflector or DotPeek or similar tools to reverse engineer the code. But that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Download the 30 day trial of [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/), and open PresentationCore, should be found at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationFramework.dll

That said, I believe WPF uses System.Windows.Data for Bindings and Data